# Convergence of $\frac1{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^n (X_k- {\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n X_k})^2$ to $\operatorname{Var}(X_i)$ with $X_i$ i.i.d

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to understand what is needed in the following problem and how to solve it [Ex. 22 of [this](https://math.unice.fr/%7Ediel/TD0stocal.pdf)]:

> Let $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables with finite $E[X_1^2]$.
>
> Show that $Z_n={\frac 1 {n-1}} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \left(X_k- {{\frac 1 n} {\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_k}}\right)^2$ for $n\ge 2$ converges a.s. to $\operatorname{Var}(X_i)$.

First of all, shall $E$ converge or $V$ converge (?) I assume that if it is "**converging**" then it's $E$ whom shall converge.

Now, how to solve it: Where is my mistake?

$E[{(X_k- {{\frac 1 n} {\sum X_t}})}^2]$=$E[X_1^2]-2E[X_1^2]+E[({{\frac 1 n} {\sum X_t}})^2]$

(since they are independent and identically disterbuted)

Now from the same reason:

$E[({{\frac 1 n} {\sum X_t}})^2]=E[X_1(X_1+...+X_n)+X_2(X_1+X_2...+X_n)...+X_n(X1+...+X_n)]$ = $\sum{E[{X_1}^2]}$

Which leads to total sum of

$...$

$E[{X_i}^2]$.

Can you help:/
**Why doesn't it converge to $V(X_1)$?**

Comment: Do you know what almost sure/everywhere convergence means? Explicitly it says that $Z_n$ are supposed to converge _almost surely_, not in $L^2$ (if that's what you're trying to do).

Comment: Hi, the power 2 is from the question. I was calculating Z not its square.

Comment: Please take care in quoting the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-\bar{X}_n)^2&=\frac{n}{n-1}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2-\frac{n}{n-1} \bar{X}_n^2 \\[1em]
&\xrightarrow{a.s.} \mathsf{E}X_1^2-(\mathsf{E}X_1)^2=\operatorname{Var}(X_1).
\end{align}

Comment: Tnx but where is $2E[X_i \bar X]$? Why is it 0? I got it equals to $E[X_i^2]$.

Comment: There is no such term.

Comment: How? $E[({X_k-\bar X_n})^2]=E[X_k^2-2X_k\bar X_n + X_n^2 ]$ Could you explain? I thought it true. Could you explain in a word or two how did you get what you got?

Comment: Why do u compute the expectation of $(X_k-\bar{X}_n)^2$? For the a.s. convergence u need to apply the SLLN to the following averages: $n^{-1}\sum X_k^2$ and $n^{-1}\sum X_k$.

Comment: Oooh thanks! I didn't know what is a.s convergence. I thought it's just expectation :). Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To be a little more precise, we are applying the following form of the strong law of large numbers:

> Let $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots$ be iid random variables satisfying $\mathbb E|Y_k|<\infty$. Then $n^{-1}\Sigma_{k\leq n}Y_k$ converges a.s. to the mean.

Note that some textbooks prove a version of this that require more assumptions, like $\mathbb E|Y_k|^2<\infty$, which we will not be able to assume here - so it is important to use this stronger version. To give you a concrete reference, I am using Theorem 3.23 in Kallenberg's probability textbook.

We are going to apply the result with $Y_k=X_k^2$, which is valid due to your assumption that $\mathbb EX_k^2<\infty$ (this is why we can only assume $\mathbb E|Y_k|<\infty$, because $\mathbb EY_k^2=\mathbb EX_k^4$ might be infinite given your assumptions). Thus, we obtain that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nY_k\overset{a.s.}\to\mathbb EY_k,
$$
or in other words
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k^2\overset{a.s.}\to\mathbb EX_1^2.\qquad(\star)
$$
In addition, we will also use the fact (follows from Jensen's inequality) that $(\mathbb E|X_k|)^2\leq \mathbb EX_k^2$ to conclude that $\mathbb E|X_k|<\infty$ as well, and therefore
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\overset{a.s.}\to\mathbb EX_1,
$$
which implies that
$$
\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right)^2\overset{a.s.}\to(\mathbb EX_1)^2,\qquad (\star\star)
$$

Okay, now the analysis is out of the way and all that is left is the algebra. Specifically, we will expand out your formula for $Z_n$ to write it as a linear combination of $(\star)$ and $(\star\star)$, and then get the limit you desire.

Comment: Wow thanks, such a great answer. This question appears to be out of my material, but now I also learnt something new! :)